# Highcharts: How to display multiple tooltips by click in multiple series with shared true

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

I search for a way to display a tooltip permanently, when the tooltip is shared. These points are very important:

1. Click on the point --> tooltip is cloned and displayed permanently
2. Click on the same point again, the clone is removed
3. Multiple tooltips are allowed to be displayed at the same time

Thanks.

Comment: You can evalute [that](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/SeCAB/1/) example

Answer (score 3):

As Sebastian pointed out in comment - you could clone tooltip.

When tooltip has `useHTML` set to false (by default it does), then you will only need to clone SVG element. See similar topic: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169997/highcharts-display-multiple-tooltips-by-click-and-vice-versa/16173297#16173297)

When `useHTML` is set to true then div element is created and appended to container of chart. You will need to clone not only SVG frame, but also HTML's div. Another issue is to check cloned tooltips only by x, because tooltip is shared.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7vkZV/14/

When useHTML is true HTML will overflow other SVG elements - to avoid this you could style HTML div with tooltip text and remove visible style in SVG tooltip. In other words - make tooltip in pure HTML.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7vkZV/15/

Comment: the useHTML example is actually what I've been trying to do, persistent on click, but also dismiss on click. now to figure out how to do this when I'm just passing in config objects in angular -_-;

Comment: @ragefuljoe If you get stacked - start a SO question and post your code or a live demo, like JSFiddle or Plunker :)

Comment: is there some way to remove the cloned tooltip by clicking on the tooltip itself? as opposed to hunting down the matching point again.

Comment: @ragefuljoe Yes. Adding element remove and updating arrays keeping track of cloned tooltips seems to be adding that feature - http://jsfiddle.net/7vkZV/24/